# Get latitude and longitude from UK grid reference using C# in an ASP.net project

Tags: c#

I am trying to find out if it is possible to convert from a given UK grid reference value like "ST2264" to its value in latitude and longitude or eastern and northing.

I have found a library called GeoUK but I couldn't found the way to transform it from a given UK grid reference.

Thanks

Comment: If you need the algorithm for converting an alphanumeric reference to numeric easting and northing see https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/os-transform/blob/master/os-transform.js#L147-L161  It should be straightforward to translate that from javascript to C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you probably need to know the datum to which you are converting. Different maps and different charts use different datums: two locations with identical latitude/longitude are not necessarily in the same physical place.

Each datum varies with its origin and the geometric model of the earth used, what with the earth not actually being spherical and all.

For instance, prior to 2005, USGS topographic maps used the North American Datum of 1927 (NAD27), they now use NAD83. GPS uses the World Geodetic System of 1984 (WGS84). IGN (French) topographic maps might use the *Reseau Geodesique Francais 1993* datum. [NOAA nav charts use different datums](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/datums.html#:%7E:text=The%20North%20American%20Vertical%20Datum,58%2C%20No.), depending on what the chart covers.

And the UK grid reference system uses the datum from the 1936 Ordnance Survey of Great Britain (OSGB-36). [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid#Datum_shift_between_OSGB_36_and_WGS_84):

> **Datum shift between OSGB 36 and WGS 84**
>
> The difference between the coordinates on different datums varies from place to place. The longitude and latitude positions on OSGB 36 are the same as for WGS 84 at a point in the Atlantic Ocean well to the west of Great Britain. In Cornwall, the WGS 84 longitude lines are about 70 metres east of their OSGB 36 equivalents, this value rising gradually to about 120 m east on the east coast of East Anglia. The WGS 84 latitude lines are about 70 m south of the OSGB 36 lines in South Cornwall, the difference diminishing to zero in the Scottish Borders, and then increasing to about 50 m north on the north coast of Scotland. (If the lines are further east, then the longitude value of any given point is further west. Similarly, if the lines are further south, the values will give the point a more northerly latitude.) The smallest datum shift is on the west coast of Scotland and the greatest in Kent.

[There are *lots* of different datums in use around the world](https://epsg.io/). [the linked site provides conversion tools].

Some references (the first of which has code and formulae for converting Ordnance Survey grid references):

- [https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html#:~:text=Back%20in%20the%201930's%2C%20the,basis%20for%20OS%20grid%20references](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html#:%7E:text=Back%20in%20the%201930%27s%2C%20the,basis%20for%20OS%20grid%20references).

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/coordinates

- https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf